# 'onMessage' not working in iOS, firebase_messaging flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase_messaging in my flutter application. Notifications are received in both android and iOS. I am using the following function for receiving notification.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessage: ${message.data}');
    });
```

This function is getting called when notification is recevied in Android. But in iOS, this function is not getting called. Is there any fix available for this issue?

Comment: Are you use IOS emulator or real device??

Comment: I am using a real device

Comment: Provide more code about config setting firebase_messaging for IOS device IOSInitializationSettings and InitializationSettings